# MongoDB: text search on nested view

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have a document in MongoDB 3.2 with the following structure:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5759815b94db5928bea3c3a5"), 
"source" : "pons1", 
"libraries" : [
    {
        "archive" : “deko1”, 
        "last_access" : ISODate("2016-06-09T14:45:04.644+0000"), 
        "books" : [
            {
                "title": "American Gods",
                "author": "Neil Gaiman"
            }, 
            {
                "title": "A Little Life",
                "author": "Hanya Yanagihara"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "archive" : “deko90”, 
        "last_access" : ISODate("2016-06-10T12:45:03.624+0000"), 
        "books" : [
            {
                "title": "Sociology of News",
                "author": "Michael Schudson"
            }, 
            {
                "title": "City of God",
                "author": "Augustine of Hippo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

There is an array (“books”) inside of another array (“libraries”).
Since the book titles are indexed as "text," I want to be able to conduct a free text search, and return only the *relevant* array elements.
For instance, if I search for the term “Gods,” I would like to see the following result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5759815b94db5928bea3c3a5"), 
"source" : "pons1", 
"libraries" : [
    {
        "archive" : “deko1”, 
        "last_access" : ISODate("2016-06-09T14:45:04.644+0000"), 
        "books" : [
            {
                "title": "American Gods",
                "author": "Neil Gaiman"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "archive" : “deko90”, 
        "last_access" : ISODate("2016-06-10T12:45:03.624+0000"), 
        "books" : [
            {
                "title": "City of God",
                "author": "Augustine of Hippo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In MongoDB 3.2, you can filter the elements of an array using “$filter” (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).
The problem is that you cannot use text search ($text) as a condition for $filter.
$text can only be used in the first stage of the aggregation pipeline ($match) (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/).
There is one obvious workaround: give up the power of MongoDB’s text search and maybe work with regex.
That does not seem a good option for me. I’d rather not lose the diacritic insensitivity and other interesting functionalities of MongoDB’s text search.

Is there a way of reconciling $filter and $text in the same MongoDB query?